# Retrieving documents from couchbase view using REST API

Tags: json, rest, couchbase, couchbase-view

I'm starting with couchbase 3.01 and I have a question about views.  The documentation I read said you should not include the full document in the index, as it will have a negative impact on both storage and performance.  Now I've created a mapping function and I'm emitting `null` for the document

e.g.

```
function(doc, meta) {
  if (doc.entity && doc.entity == 'desert') {
    emit(doc.type, null);
  }
}
```

This should create an index for my various types of deserts (cookie, ice cream, cake).  When I save the view, and click the 'Show Results' button in the admin console, I see all of the keys with the associated value of `null`.

If I change my mapping function to include the document e.g.

```
function(doc, meta) {
  if (doc.entity && doc.entity == 'desert') {
    emit(doc.type, doc);
  }
}
```

I get the results I expect, but, I'm concerned that this is an anti-pattern.  It seems like there used to be a querystring parameter `include_docs` which would dereference the document, but it doesn't appear in the documentation.  Should I include the full document in the indexes I generate?  If not, how do I retrieve the document by key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is to have a view defined without full DOC included. Then you can use Couchbase client library specific for your application platform (e.g. Java, Python, Node.js, .Net, etc.) to access documents from your view by setting flag include_docs(when needed).

The **REST API should not be used to read or write data** to the server. Data operations, such as set and get for example, are handled by [Couchbase SDKs](http://couchbase.com/develop).

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question - I'm just looking for a way to see the view contents via the browser while I'm doing development.  I plan to use the SDK from my application.

Comment: Oh, for dev purpose you can define views with doc returned...its just not recommended for production. Also CB Web Console view contents pane shows url that you can click to open in a new window - that is nothing more but rest call.